# jQuery smooth-scrolling navigation menu bar

Tags: jquery, wordpress-theming, smooth-scrolling

So I have been experimenting with RootsTheme (which uses Bootstrap), Wordpress (from Joomla! background) and Pagodabox;

here's the result of it: http://ajmalafif.com/

However I am having some known issues with the navigation bar with any javascript solution that I've tried:

route #1) Chris Coyier's smooth-scrolling

Currently my site runs on this one.

what doesn't work
- for smaller screen or when browser resized, the nav will stop at awkwardly at much higher height (since it's set to offset at -90px on > 1200px screen width)

what works
- the next & previous link button for images work (click on mysite.com#link doesn't conflict between the nav bar anchor and the image link click anchor)

example of the code: http://jsfiddle.net/ajmalafif/LvPUC/1/

route #2) William Malo's getElementbyId

I like and used this solution at first.

what doesn't work
- it doesn't have offset solution so it stops directly on the h1 title and blocks the view of it.
- it conflicts with the bootstrap-carousel.js where upon click the image carousel, the screen/navbar will moves and align the image with the top of the browser.

what works
- It works with any browser size (and upon resized) and targets/arrives accordingly.

example of the code: http://jsfiddle.net/ajmalafif/bReUF/

--

It may looks like route#1 is the clear winner but like what's currently running on my site, it has few glitches especially when view, say inside an iPad. So is there any pointer/help I can get to make this works either by;

- a href target is accurately offset regardless of the browser width (maybe a solution to have diff offset based on diff browser's width)?, OR
- a way to offset when using getElementbyId solution (see route#2) AND to make it compatible with bootstrap-carousel.js (so it doesn't move itself when click another image carousel # anchor tag)?

Thanks for your concern and time for taking a look at this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can calculate browser's height and return scrolling for that variable;

[here is DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/LvPUC/6/)

```
var browH = $(window).height();
            //alert(browH);
    if ( browH < 500 ) {
      $(scrollElem).animate({scrollTop: targetOffset-80}, 800,function() { location.has = target;});
    }
    else if ( browH > 500 ) {
       $(scrollElem).animate({scrollTop: targetOffset-80}, 400,function() { location.has = target;});
    }
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the pointer! I'm working on making it to work with my site (somehow it doesn't work on my site setup).

But that should be good enough for me to start working from. Appreciate it! 

And require 15 reputation to vote up is ridiculous SO!

Comment: I'm glad i could help :) you dont need to vote up, just select it as answer if it worked (: