# How to auto scroll a div at configurable speed?

Tags: jquery, html

I am building a scrolling application that requires users to configure the scroll speed.

Here is my current code:

```
function scroll() {
        var overlay = document.getElementById('overlay');
        overlay.scrollTop = overlay.scrollTop + 2;
    }

    function togglescrolling() {
        if (goscrolling == false) {
            window.clearInterval(scrollinterval);
            scrollinterval = window.setInterval(scroll, 0);
            goscrolling = true;
        } else {
            goscrolling = false;
            window.clearInterval(scrollinterval);
        }
    }
```

This code works and it autoscrolls to bottom of the page as planned but it scrolls very fast and I would like to configure this speed.

I used jQuery Animate in the past and not sure if it is really helping.

Comment: That code doesn't scroll down, though .. where is the code that does the animating?

Comment: There is no animating. I just need an autoscroll on a div elment

Comment: Can you show us using jsfiddle.net?

Comment: OK, I added the full code

Comment: This answer might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11326531/jquery-smooth-scrolling-navigation-menu-bar/11326646#11326646

Comment: Thanks @barlas but no help for me there. I am looking for a simple autoscroll based on my functions above. I am able to autoscroll but now I need the scroll speed to be configurable to be slow or fast based on user's preferences

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To animate page scroll with jQuery:

```
$('html,body').animate({scrollTop: /* numeric pixel value here*/}, duration);
```

Can get the distance needed to scroll to specific element by getting that element `offset().top`

```
var myDivTop= $('#myDiv').offset().top;
$('html,body').animate({scrollTop:myDivTop}, duration);
```

Comment: I am not looking for animation. All I looking is to autoscroll at a speed that is defined by the user.

Comment: will have to animate that somehow. Can add `steps` to `animate()`

Comment: @charlieftl, please see my code above. I am able to autoscroll but not able to  change the speed of my autoscroll. That is all I am looking for now.

Comment: can change the interval but speed won;t be smooth. Using animation easy to pass user defined value in

Comment: not sure why you are trying to reinvent the wheel. This animation method is very common